# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined yet works fine

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, typeerror

I have two arrays as follows:

```
bookingHistory: Booking[] = [];
currentBookings: any[] = [];
```

They are both populated further down the code. `bookingHistory` is an array of `Booking` and `currentBookings` has an array of `Booking` arrays.

My html template has the following:

```
<table class="w3-table w3-striped">
  <tbody> 
    <tr *ngFor="let booking of bookingHistory; let i = index">
      <td>{{booking?.level}}</td>
      <td>{{booking?.date}}</td>
      <td>{{booking?.room}}</td>
      <td>AM</td>
      <td>{{booking?.am_dept}}</td>
      <td>{{booking?.am_surg}}</td>

      <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.level}}</td>
      <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.date}}</td>
      <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.room}}</td>
      <td>AM</td>
      <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.am_dept}}</td>
      <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.am_surg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So this works exactly as expected yet every line with `currentBookings[i][0]` triggers this error in the console.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Am I missing something that will cause me future grief?

UPDATE:

**bookingHistory** is an array of Bookings as follows: `[{…}, {…}, {…}]`

A `Booking` is structured as follows:

```
{url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/booking/3203/", date: "2017-09-05", level: 
4, room: 5, am_dept: "Cardiac (A)", …}
```

Whereas **currentBookings** is as follows: `[[{…}], [{…}], [{…}]]`

Comment: could you confirm `currentBookings` is an array of arrays?, if its 1D array then try `currentBookings[i]` only

Comment: @anoop updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an Async problem in the end.

In the fraction of a second between the second array being populated the `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error was triggered multiple times although it rendered to the screen seemingly fine.

Fixed by adding a counter and a `boolean` variable to ensure the second array had been populated before the screen was rendered. And wrapping the template with it.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="finished">
  <table class="w3-table w3-striped">
    <tbody> 
      <tr *ngFor="let booking of bookingHistory; let i = index">
        <td>{{booking?.level}}</td>
        <td>{{booking?.date}}</td>
        <td>{{booking?.room}}</td>
        <td>AM</td>
        <td>{{booking?.am_dept}}</td>
        <td>{{booking?.am_surg}}</td>

        <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.level}}</td>
        <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.date}}</td>
        <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.room}}</td>
        <td>AM</td>
        <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.am_dept}}</td>
        <td>{{currentBookings[i][0]?.am_surg}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

It now works as expected error free.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `bookingHistory.length > currentBookings.length`, so after some iteration `currentBookings[i]` is **outOfRange** and becomes `undefined`.

Make sure to iterate on `currentBookings` array till it's last index., or make both arrays equal in length.

to iterate on `currentBookings` you can use `<ng-container>` which actually doesn't render on HTML

Comment: They are in fact the same length and the way they are populated they can never not be. So unfortunately this is not it either.

Comment: try declaring `currentBookings: any[ ][ ] = [ [ ] ];` as multidimensional

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added an answer if you are interested in what was the problem in the end. Wasn't aware of `<ng-container>` so thank you for that.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that may be a syntax error, you are missing a semicolon while declaring variables in your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let booking of bookingHistory; let i = index">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<tr *ngFor="#booking of bookingHistory; #i = index">
```

Instead of

```
<tr *ngFor="let booking of bookingHistory; let i = index">
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but is this not just an outdated way of declaring a local variable? Which is what `let` is doing already.
Either way it doesn't run.